Terraform provider schema: how do I define a ListNestedAttribute containing an object with any arbitrary config?
I want to define a schema where there is a ListNestedAttribute, containing a list of objects. Within those objects, one property is dynamic, in the sense that it contains some form of arbitrary object. I’d use a Dynamic object but that is not supported within collections.
resp.Schema = schema.Schema {
  Attributes: map[string]schema.Attribute {
    "my_list": schema.ListNestedAttributes {
      Required: true,
      NestedObject: schema.NestedAttributeObject {
        Attributes: map[string]schema.Attribute {
          "config": schema.Something {
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Here I want to know what Something should be, or how I otherwise require the user to supply a list of elements, where each element has a property called config and which can contain any arbitrary values. Is this possible?

tftypes does not support generics due to the implementation using the underlying gRPC API. To be compatible a list(object) in the schema like you are using would need both a corresponding struct with tftypes and a map[string]attr.Type{} for conversions, and these also would cause issues using generics as they are both type defined already.
It would probably be more feasible for this to be supported first for the new provider defined functions feature that Brian implemented in the recent terraform-plugin-go and terraform-plugin-framework releases. I also requested that feature already, so hopefully it appears on the Roadmap, but the plugin team is very busy as it is.
